# General way to determine whether a subset of a vector space is an affine space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, affine-varieties

Given some implicit equations or a definition of a subset of a vector space, what is the requirement for it to define an affine subspace. I'm looking for something analogous to the test for vector subspaces (closed under adittion and scalar multiplication):

Let $V$ be vector space over a field  $\mathcal{K}$ and $S\subseteq V$ a subset, $S$ is a subspace iff $\space \forall s,s'\in S$ and $\forall \lambda \in \mathcal{K}$ we have $s+s' \in S$ and $\lambda s \in S$.

I am aware the definition for an affine subspace is the set $A = a+S$ where $a$ is a "position" vector and $S$ is a vector subspace, I understand this definition.
However, I'm under the impression that affine spaces are not in general closed under addition or multiplication.

How do I go about proving for example that:
$\{(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, x_{4}) ∈ \mathcal{K}^4 \space
|\space x_{2} = x_{4} = 1, x_{1} + x_{3} = −1\}$ is in fact an affine space, or that $\{v\in \mathbb{R}^n | v_{1}^2+v_{2}^2+... +v_{n}^2=1 \}$ is obviously not since it's the unit sphere?

What is the general procedure?

Comment: Fix an arbitrary vector $\vec a\in A$ and then you are asking if the set $\{\vec v -\vec a \,|\,\vec v\in A\}$ is a vector space. In your first case, for instance, let $\vec a=(-1,1,0,1)$ (for example) so the difference set consists of vectors of the form $(x+1, 0,-x-1,0)$ which is the same as $(x,0,-x,0)$ which is clearly a vector space.